# brightness stuck at minimum

Tags: xfce, brightness, backlight

when i lower the brightness to a certain low degree (way over 0) the screen goes dark and is stuck thus; only with the use of a flashlight and the room in the dark i can barely see the screen. this is both using the Fn keys and the Power Manager Plugin in the xfce panel

i have xfce 4.18, kernel 5.4.192-pclos1, GPU llvmpipe (LLVM 14.0.16, 128 bits) Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics. brightness is handled by /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight; acpi_video0 is not handled, its brightness set at maximum